# JavaFx Media type is not acessible

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a JavaFx project in Visual Studio Code. And I was wanting to release a sound, but I ended up having the following problem:

> **The type javafx.scene.media.Media is not accessibleJava(16778666)**
>
> **The type javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer is not accessibleJava(16778666)**

I've already added your modules and also seen them on the internet to add to pom.xml:

```
  modules:

    "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml, javafx.media",

  Pom.xml:

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
```

I didn't find anyone commenting on this specific error, if you can help me I would be very grateful

Note: The paths are correct as the other packages are working normally

The code:

```
    package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("urna"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Urna Eletrônica");
        stage.show();
    }

    public void songMedia(String path) {
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the whitespace in the `add-modules` argument, between the comma and `javafx.media`.

Comment: Is this an actual compile-time or run-time error? Or is this only something that VS Code is complaining about?

Comment: it's something vsCode keeps complaining and I also removed the module space and nothing

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add it manually to your dependencies first
all info available on the JavaFX maven plugin github page
https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way you have placed your path to the JavaFX library, Visual studio is reading the Javafx library incorrectly.
On top of the Visual Studio menu,

- Click on **Run**
- Then select **Open Configurations**
- Inside the curly braces under **"configurations"** add a comma then press **Enter**
- Then add  the lines below:

**`"vmArgs": "--module-path=PATH_TO_JAVAFX_LIB --add-modules=MODULE_1,MODULES_2"`**

Note: An example of the above arguments with the correct path format is as below;

> **`"vmArgs": "--module-path=lib/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules=javafx.media,javafx.controls"`**